# how to play pcm raw data in java

Tags: java, audio, pcm

I have PCM samples in a short array. What is the best way to play this out?
The format is 8000Hz, Mono, 16 bit, big endian.
(The PCM samples are generated in the code and not read through some file)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [javax.sound.sampled](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/package-summary.html) package it's pretty much straightforward, but you have to use some boilerplate.

Here's a good tutorial on that: [www.wikijava.org/wiki/Play_a_wave_sound_in_Java](http://www.wikijava.org/wiki/Play_a_wave_sound_in_Java)

Basically you have to create an `InputStream` from your array and use that to create an `AudioInputStream`. There you have to specify the format of your audio data.

Then you open an output stream (`SourceDataLine`) and copy the bytes from the audio stream into that stream.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried this method but couldn't play the pcm data properly, I could only get noise. Probably some config issue with AudioFormat. But I found a work around: I dumped the pcm data to a FileOutputStream (/tmp/x.wav)and exec'd aplay command (alsa utility in linux) to play /tmp/x.wav.

Comment: The `wikijava` link is dead.