# What is an easy to use library for audio streaming?

Tags: java, audio, streaming

I need to play audio stream and I'm looking for some library with support for multiple codecs and PCM(raw data). I also need to adjust the pace of audio. I'm aware of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1157570/3952906) however I don't know how to adjust the pace. I hoped I'll just import some library that will do all the things, but there are so many of them that I'm kind of lost. I was looking at Java Media Framework but it seems to be quite overkill. Thanks

Comment: hey, this may help you men http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567686/libgdx-change-pitch-in-music